# Spring Integration: Error Channel not available in XML

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

Hi I am using Spring integration with JMS integration and i noticed that when i try to use error-channel in my jms-message-drive-outbound-adapter, it give below error;

As per suggestions for my previous questions , i want to retrieve exception and rollback transaction so that i dont lose message. How do i achieve that if error-channel is not possible.

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'error-channel' is not allowed to appear in element 'jms:message-driven-channel-adapter'.
```

My XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd">

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="requestChannelAdapter" channel="requestChannel" 
    container="requestListenerContainer" error-channel=""/>


    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
        auto-startup="true" sync="true" channel="inputToKafka" topic="test">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

Is it replaced with something else in recent releases.

My POM File is listed below for reference in case it is due to version mismatch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.dzone.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpmc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jpmc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore it; it appears your IDE is using the schema from the internet - see the note at the top of it...

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd

```
<!--
       +++++ IMPORTANT +++++

     This schema is for the 1.0 version of Spring Integration JMS. We cannot update it to the current schema
     because that will break any applications using 1.0.3 or lower. For subsequent versions, the unversioned
     schema is resolved from the classpath and obtained from the jar.
     Please refer to github:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-jms/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jms/config

     for the latest schema. 
-->
```

You can either ignore it, or use a Spring-Aware IDE (Spring Tool Suite - STS, IntelliJ IDEA, etc) that knows how to find the current schema on the class path via `/META-INF/spring.schemas`.

If you are already using STS (or eclipse with the Spring IDE plugins) then be sure to enable "Spring Nature" on the project.